# Adding features while creating User in mvc using checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

i want to create users with special features in mvc. when user is going to create i want to assign some special feature to each user like particular user having his own house, having his own car using checkbox selection. the particular feature is reside in different table named feature. then how can i add those features with user while creating the user.

i have created a view model named ViewModelUserWithFeature

```
public class ViewModelUserWithFeature
{
        public User User { get; set; }
        public Feature Feature { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> feature { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<User> IUser { get; set; }
        private UserDbContext userDbContext;
        private IUserService userService;

 public void ViewUserList()
        {
            userService = new RoleService(userDbContext);
            IUser = userService.GetUsers();

        }
        public void AddNewUser(User userAdd)
        {
            userService = new UserService(userDbContext);
            User = userService.AddUser(userAdd);
            userService.SaveUser();
        }
}
```

here is my view in which i want to two textboxes and a list of features which are going to select by checkbox and attached with the user.

```
@model App.ViewModel.ViewModelUserWithFeature
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post))
    {
 <div>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
 <div>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.UserAddres)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserAddres)
            </div>
@for(int i=0; i < Model.Feature; i++)
{
<div class="cb"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"></div>
 <div class="per-content">
<label for="1"> Model.Feature.FeatureName</div>
}
<div>
 <button type="submit" id="btn-rd">Submit</button>
</div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(User user)
        {
 ViewModelUserWithFeature viewModelUserWithFeature = new ViewModelUserWithFeature(usertDbContext);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {


                    viewModelUserWithFeature.AddNewUser(user);


                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", viewModelUserWithFeature);
}
```

not able to achieve that what i have tried so far i have mentioned . please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use view models to represent what you display and edit

```
public class FeatureVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class UserVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public List<FeatureVM> Features { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  UserVM model = new UserVM();
  model.Features = // map all available features
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserVM model)
{

}
```

View

```
@model UserVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
  .....
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Features.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Features[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Features[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Features[i].IsSelected, Model.Features[i].Name)
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Comment: model.Features = // map all available features
wat doses this mean ?? sorry to ask a silly question but i am new to mvc thats why i am asking.

Comment: Currently you have a list of `Feature` objects stored somewhere (in a database) which I assume have an `ID` and `Name` property. When you create a new User (`UserVM` class) you would get the list of features from the db. But because `Feature` does not contain a property to indicate if its selected (`IsSelected`) you need to create a new instance of `FeatureVM` for each `Feature` (i.e you map the `ID` and `Name` from `Feature` to `FeatureVM`)

Comment: Note you can use tools like [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to make mapping from one type (`Feature`) to another type (`FeatureVM`) easy, but it could be just something like `foreach(Feature f in db.Features) { model.Features.Add(new FeatureVM { ID = f.ID, Name = f.Name }) };`

Comment: sir can i have an example for this code model.Features = // map all available features according to your example, i mean how can i pass the list value  from controller to view

Comment: I've given you an example in my last comment. What more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

try with this, in you Model of Feature add a new property

```
public bool isFeatureOf { get; set; }
```

also in your model for the method AddNewUser change it to

```
    public void AddNewUser(User userAdd,List<Feature> features)
    {
        userService = new UserService(userDbContext);
        User = userService.AddUser(userAdd);
        userService.SaveUser();

        //featureService = new FeatureService(yourdbcontext)
        foreach (Feature item in features)
        {
            //save to db
          featureService.SaveFeature(item,User.Id);
          //i don't know if in your database you already have a table,colum or something to map the features by user
        }

    }
```

then in your view

```
for(int index=0; index < Model.Features.Count(); index++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.Features[index].NameFeature) 
  @Html.Raw(Model.Features[index].NameFeature)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>Model.Features[index].isFeatureOf)

}
```

also in your view you'll need to change this

```
     <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
    <div>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.UserAddres)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserAddres)
        </div>
```

to:

```
      <div>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>Model.User.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.User.UserName)
        </div>
   <div>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.UserAddres)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>Model.User.UserAddres)
        </div>
```

in your controller change your param to get the whole Model like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ViewModelUserWithFeature model)
    {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              model.AddNewUser(model.User,model.Features);
            } 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", viewModelUserWithFeature);
    }
```

hope this can help you

Comment: sir i dont want to add any column to my model simply i want to view the list of features in my view, i will catch the id of the checkbox using jquery dynamically. the main problem is can not able to diplay the list of features when i am doing this
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FeatureList.Count; i++)
         {
              @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FeatureList[i].FeatureId)
             
         }
getting some error like can not implicitly convert type int to bool