# The value 'some value' is invalid when submitting form with checkboxes in MVC 5

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, mvc-editor-templates

I have a form in an MVC 5 application that has several checkboxes to allow different categories to be selected. However when submitting, I get the message The value 'some value' is invalid. That appears where the error message is for the checkboxes. I have looked and not found a solution.

I have an editor template:

```
@Modeltype ienumerable(Of be_Categories)
@For Each x In Model
      @<label>@x.CategoryName</label>
      @<input type="checkbox" name="PostCategory" value="@x.CategoryID"/>    
Next
```

And in the form I call:

```
   @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.PostCategory, htmlAttributes:=
       New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.PostCategory,
         New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.PostCategory, "",
         New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
```

And in controller:

```
  Public Function CreateNewPost(ByVal post As be_PostsViewModel) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then             
            Dim p As New be_PostsViewModel              
            p.PostTitle = post.PostTitle
            p.PostDateCreated = post.PostDateCreated
            p.IsPublished = post.IsPublished
            p.PostGuid = Guid.NewGuid
            p.PostSummary = post.PostSummary
            p.PostText = post.PostText
            p.PostCategory = post.PostCategory
           _POSTREPO.Insert(p)

            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
            Return View(post)
    End Function
```

My Post ViewModel:

```
Public Class be_PostsViewModel
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Property Author As String
    <DisplayName("Title")> <Required(ErrorMessage:="Your post must have a title")> Public Property PostTitle As String
    <DisplayName("My Snarky Text")> Public Property PostSummary As String
    <DisplayName("Post")> Public Property PostText As String
    <UIHint("DateCreated")> <DisplayName("Date Created")> Property PostDateCreated As DateTime?
    <DisplayName("Publish")> Public Property IsPublished As Boolean
    Public Property PostGuid As Guid
    Public Property BlogId As Guid
    <DataType(DataType.MultilineText)> <UIHint("Tags")> <DisplayName("Tags")> Public Property PostTags As ICollection(Of be_PostTag)
    <DisplayName("Category")> <UIHint("Categories")> Public Property PostCategory As ICollection(Of be_Categories)
End Class
```

And the Category Model:

```
Partial Public Class be_Categories
    <Key>
    Public Property CategoryRowID As Integer    
    Public Property BlogID As Guid    
    Public Property CategoryID As Guid    
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property CategoryName As String    
    <StringLength(200)>
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property be_Posts As ICollection(Of be_Posts)    
    Public Property be_PostCategory As ICollection(Of be_PostCategory)
    Public Property ParentID As Guid?
End Class
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Also I should mention that I am working with existing database and data so used EF Code First from Database.

Comment: You `EditorTemplate` is creating a array of `int` (assuming `CategoryID` is typeof `int`) with the name `PostCategory` which has no relationship to your model. You need to include the model definition to understand what your trying to do

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the code for the view model and the categories model.

Comment: Your property `PostCategory` is a collection of object `be_Categories`. In you `EditorTemplate` (which your doing wrong anyway) you are generating collection of checkboxes with the name `PostCategory`. When this posts back, this generates a collection of `int` which cannot be bound to to a collection of `be_Categories` so the binding fails.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you trying to do, but either your `be_PostsViewModel` needs a property `int[] CategoryID` to bind the selected category ID's to, or (better) you need a view model for `be_Categories` with a `bool IsSelected` property so you can use strongly typed `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` method` [as per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066154/adding-features-while-creating-user-in-mvc-using-checkbox/27069996#27069996)

Comment: OK thanks for that, I think I understand what I need to do now. As far as the EditorTemplate goes should I be using @Html.Checkbox or CheckboxFor?

Comment: Always best to use the strongly typed helpers (`CheckBoxFor()`) They produce the same output but it you change the name of a property or mis-spell it you could spend hours trying to track down your errors if you use `CheckBox()`. As far as using an `EditorTemplate` for a collection, the template should be named the same as the class name (`be_Categories.cshtml)` and the model should be the object, not `IEnumerable<T>` (`@ModelType be_Categories`) and remove the `UIHint("Categories")` from the property. The `EditorFor()` method takes care of correctly rendering the collection for you.