# Pre-processing Form data before Model validation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fairly new to MVC, but have quite a bit of experience in development in general, and am having an issue with MVC request life cycle it seems.

Will try to keep this simple, even tho the project is a bit complex in some areas.

I have a view bound to a view model that has a few complex list properties. These properties are displayed via checkboxes who's IDs are not directly related to any property in the model, but instead related to the IDs of the objects in the List<>. Because of this, the checked values do not automatically get applied to the model on POST.

To get around that, I added code in the Action method in the controller that parses the proper controls (in the Request.Form collection) and assigns the checked/selected value to the proper list items in the model.

This works perfectly up to a point.

Now, I also use Fluent Validation, and the problem is when performing custom validation rules when posting a new model to the server. The Validation routine is firing BEFORE the controller's action method, and thus before my processing of the list objects.

So, my question is, is there a way I can override the initial call to the model validation so I can just call the validation manually after my processing? I know I can do that which will fix the problem without overriding the initial call, but some of the validation takes a bit of time to process since it requires linq queries to a live database, so I do not want the validation to fire 2 times - that will quite literally double the time it takes to return no matter if the model is valid or not.

EDIT: Adding a example:

```
namespace Models
{
  [Validator(typeof(MemberValidator))]
  public class ViewMember
  {
    public int MemberID { get; set; }        
    public short RegionID { get; set; }       
    public List<PropTypeInfo> PropTypes { get; set; }

  }
}
```

PropTypeInfo class:

```
public class PropTypeInfo
{
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public PropTypeInfo(byte i, string n, string d, bool sel)
    {
        ID = i;
        Name = n;
        Description = d;
        Selected = sel;
    }
    public static List<PropTypeInfo> GetAll(bool selected = false)
    {
        List<PropTypeInfo> output = new List<PropTypeInfo>();

        OpenAccess.Context context = new OpenAccess.Context();

        var list = (from f in context.Prop_Types orderby f.PropType select f).ToList();

        foreach (OpenAccess.WebrentzServerPayments.Models.Prop_Type p in list)
            output.Add(new PropTypeInfo(p.PropType, p.PropName, p.DisplayText, selected));

        return output;
    }
}
```

now here is the code in the view that renders the checkboxes for each item in the list:

```
<div class="Column Emp-PropTypes">
  @foreach (WebrentzServerPayments.Models.PropTypeInfo ptype in Model.PropTypes)
  {
    <div style="float:right;width:20%;font-weight:bold;">
      @Html.CheckBox("ptype_" + ptype.ID, ptype.Selected, new {Value=ptype.ID}) @Html.Raw("&nbsp;") @ptype.Name
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

And here is the code I use in the Controller Action method to pull that data back in to the List:

```
foreach (PropTypeInfo info in member.PropTypes)
            info.Selected = form[string.Format("ptype_{0}", info.ID)].Contains(info.ID.ToString());
```

As a little background, a "PropType" is a type of property (house, condo, apartment) - there are about 2 dozen of them, and more can be added/removed at any time. The list in the class called "PropTypes" is first populated with the Name, Description and ID from a table in the database that lists all the available proptypes for that region.

We then will mark the proptypes as "selected" if the user has chosen that particular type. Those are saved to a table called Member.PropTypes (MemberID, ProptypeID).

So, at runtime the list will contain one record for each available proptype and the selected property will be set to yes if that user has selected it. That makes it easy to render the full list in the view...

Its actually quite a bit more complex as there are almost a dozen such lists, but each works the exact same way just with different data, as well as about 200 additional properties that are easier to manage. Only these lists are causing the issue.

Any help appreciated!

Dave

Comment: Not unless you were to create your own custom model binder that ignored the properties you did not want to validate. But since the main reason for a view model is to display/edit what you want, this suggests your view model is wrong. Hard to tell without any code, but best guess is you need view models for your collection objects that includes an `IsSelected` property that gets bound using `CheckBoxFor()`

Comment: Hmm. I have thought of that, but not sure how it would be done.

As an example, if you had a list of items:

List<Person>

And assume Person has a IsSelected property, as well as an ID that identifies the person and a Name for display, and assuming this list can contain dozens of people and each one needs a checkbox, how would you refer to the checkbox's Name property in order to bind it on the model?  (Model.People[?].ID = x)

Comment: You know what, your right about not having a code example. Let me modify the original post with something that fits what I have.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066154/adding-features-while-creating-user-in-mvc-using-checkbox/27069996#27069996) might help to understand what I am suggesting

Comment: Thanks for that Stephen - that gives me something to try. I did not think I could map them like that. Ill try it on one collection and see if that works. Shouldnt take long to find out :)

Comment: That worked like a charm Stephen. Thank you very much! I would never have thought that would work with something in a unordered list. Awesome. Thank you very much!